# web3js Gas Estimation

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain

I was wondering if the pattern below is correct for sending a transaction with the correct gas limit.

```
this.contracts.myContract.methods.myMethod.getEstimatedGas().then(gas => {
  this.contracts.myContract.methods.myMethod.cacheSend(
    ["prop1", "prop2"],
    {
      gas
    }
  );
});
```

I've also read that adding 10% to the estimate could be sensible.

Or should I just go with whatever prices Metamask populates when making the method call?

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate the gas cost of your transaction using `web3.eth.estimateGas`.

Example:

```
var result = web3.eth.estimateGas({
to: "0xc4abd0339eb8d57087278718986382264244252f", 
data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
});
console.log(result); // "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015
```

I would take this estimate and multiply by a factor of 1.1 to be safe.

See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethestimategas for further reference.

Comment: I am indeed using the web3.eth.estimateGas method, I should have been clearer in my original question and code.

I've updated the question now :)

Answer (score 1):

I use to follow this pattern that should be useful:

```
await contractInstance.methods.transfer(self.state.owner, self.state.value)
         .send({
            from: accounts[0],
            gas: '5000000'
          })
```

With gas you are setting up the gasLimit.